# Unknown Generics

Tags: c++, sql, json

I am attempting to create a database system modeling SQL, where each table is stored in a JSON file. Really not focusing on speed at the moment as this is more an exercise in communication. I came up with the following markup,

```
{
  "table": {
    "auto_increment": 3,
    "last_edited": 1423163442
  },
  "definitions": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "kind": "INT",
      "length": 8,
      "default": "NONE",
      "index": "PRIMARY",
      "auto_increment": true
    },
    {
      "name": "username",
      "kind": "VARCHAR",
      "length": 25,
      "default": "NONE",
      "index": "UNIQUE",
      "auto_increment": false
    },
    {
      "name": "name_last",
      "kind": "VARCHAR",
      "length": 25,
      "default": "NONE",
      "index": "NONE",
      "auto_increment": false
    },
    {
      "name": "name_first",
      "kind": "VARCHAR",
      "length": 25,
      "default": "NONE",
      "index": "NONE",
      "auto_increment": false
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "username": "Neat-O",
      "name_first": "Kenny",
      "name_last": "Hill"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "12thAggie",
      "name_first": "Reville",
      "name_last": "18"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "I_Like_Cheese",
      "name_first": "Shh",
      "name_last": "Secret"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this file I need to be able to read in and essentially create an object in C++ representing this table, or any table in SQL for that matter. It is a limited implementation of SQL, so let's just consider this markup to hover around the edge of the intended functionality. In my current design I am thinking it would be best to define abstract column objects, that can essentially be stacked together to form a whole table. Operations can be performed on all the columns as though they are a whole table, and then saved back to disk. Again, I am not concerned with performance at the moment mostly readability and implementation. So my question to you C++ gurus is this, how would you interpret this data and manipulate it once instantiated as a C++ object? I have been exploring generics but I keep getting hung up on the "selectable" data types, INTS, VARCHAR, etc... My current class "kind" (for a column has the following members:

```
template <class T>
class Kind
{
private:
    int length;
    string kind;
    string default_value;
    string index;
    int auto_increment;
    vector<T> data;
}
```

However, when trying to create the table I would need to somehow create a type that allows for multiple types of generics.

```
vector<Kind<?>> table;
```

Where  allows for VARCHAR, INT, etc... Any help with this would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/)

Comment: maybe create enum like `enum SqlType{ Varchar, Int, ... };` and then do `vector<pair<SqlType, string>>` and store everyting as string. The second solution is to make Varchar, Int etc classes and make them all inherit from some class, and then implement the logic that way(virtual functions)